# error {"Element 'faultstring' with namespace name '' was not found. Line 6, position 126."} when try to connect nusoap web service from C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services, nusoap

I try to create a nusoap web service (I use xampp and .net beans) and connect to it using a C# app (use visual studio). but I encounter this error:

> {"Server returned an invalid SOAP Fault.  Please see InnerException for more details."}

the inner error is:

> {"Element 'faultstring' with namespace name '' was not found. Line 6, position 126."}

As [this source](https://sourceforge.net/p/nusoap/discussion/193579/thread/9a5aff36/) suggested I changed properties order for `function serialize()` in `class.soap_fault.php` file but it still gives the same error.

I tried restarting the computer so I now it is not a catch problem.

Also the only other change I made in nusoap library was changing `var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';` to `var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';` in `nusoap.php` file to solve encoding problem.

in C# I have the following code:

```
SR1.demoPortTypeClient client = new SR1.demoPortTypeClient();
var result = client.gettext("hello");
MessageBox.Show("*" + result + "*");
```

and in php:

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
$server=new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("demo");
$namespace = "demo";
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;
$server->register(
        "gettext",//name of function
        array("txt"=>'xsd:string'),//inputs
        array("return"=>'xsd:string'),//outputs
        $namespace,// namespace
        false,// soapaction (use default)
        'rpc',// style: rpc or document
        'encoded',// use: encoded or literal
        'Return same text'// description for method
        );

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

where `gettext` function is:

```
<?php
function gettext($txt)
{
    return $txt;
}
```

current `serialize()` function is:

```
function serialize(){
        $ns_string = '';
        foreach($this->namespaces as $k => $v){
            $ns_string .= "\n  xmlns:$k=\"$v\"";
        }
        $return_msg =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.$this->soap_defencoding.'"?>'.
            '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"'.$ns_string.">\n".
                '<SOAP-ENV:Body>'.
                '<SOAP-ENV:Fault>'.
                    $this->serialize_val( $this->faultcode,   'faultcode'   ) .
                            $this->serialize_val( $this->faultstring, 'faultstring' ) .
                            $this->serialize_val( $this->faultactor,  'faultactor'  ) .
                            $this->serialize_val( $this->faultdetail, 'detail'      ) .
                '</SOAP-ENV:Fault>'.
                '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'.
            '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
        return $return_msg;
    }
```

I expected changing order of properties solves the problem, however I still receive the same error. I searched a lot but couldn't find any other solve for the error.

Comment: If you are using a `Web Reference` in Visual Studio right click the reference and select "Update Web Reference" might fix the issue

Comment: @Minijack , tried but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reason I do not know, there is two definition for `function serialize()` with same body in two different file. One in `class.soap_fault.php` and another in `nusoap.php` and you need to change the method body in the second one (`nusoap.php`). I do not know is there any condition you need to change other one or not.

---

For other ones who may reach this post I add some problems you may encounter and their solve:

Exception :

> Encodes were different (windows uses 'utf-8' and this uses
>   'ISO-8859-1')

Reason: Encoding type are different in server and client.

Solve: In `nusoap.php` file changing var `$soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';` to `var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';`

See: this [source](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/304429/get-UTF-8-char-in-WSDL-NuSoap)

---

Exception :

> Server returned an invalid SOAP Fault. Please see InnerException for
>   more details

Inner:

> Element ‘faultstring’ with namespace name ” was not found. Line 6,
>   position 126

Reason: Difference in order of fault properties

Solve: in `nusoap.php` change `function serialize()` to following:

```
function serialize() {
      $ns_string = '';
      foreach( $this->namespaces as $k => $v ) {
        $ns_string .= "\n  xmlns:$k=\"$v\"";
      }
      $return_msg =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . $this->soap_defencoding . '"?>' .
        '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"' . $ns_string . ">\n" .
          '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' .
            '<SOAP-ENV:Fault>' .
              $this->serialize_val( $this->faultcode,   'faultcode'   ) .
              $this->serialize_val( $this->faultstring, 'faultstring' ) .
              $this->serialize_val( $this->faultactor,  'faultactor'  ) .
              $this->serialize_val( $this->faultdetail, 'detail'      ) .
            '</SOAP-ENV:Fault>' .
          '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' .
        '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
      return $return_msg;
}
```

See: this [source](https://sourceforge.net/p/nusoap/discussion/193579/thread/9a5aff36/)

---

Exception:

> {"error in msg parsing:\nxml was empty, didn't parse!"}

Reason: The following php function is not valid in current version:

solve: use following code for php version 5.6.0 to before 7.0.0

```
$POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
$server->service($POST_DATA);
```

and for version 7.0.0 and later use:

```
@$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

See: This [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038144/nusoap-soap-env-xml-was-empty-didnt-parse-message)

---

Exception:

> {"method ''('*function name here*'('*function name here*') not
>   defined in service('' '')"}

or simply:

> method '' not defined in service.

Reason: When using C# to connecting to the `nusoap` web server. It is disable to find methods defined in other files/classes.

Solve: define all method in the same file as you write web service

See: This [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MucfykNebGE)

Note: If you know a way to overcome this problem and let define methods in other files/classes (= make cleaner code) please comment it.

---

Exception:

> {"Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation '*method
>   name*'."}

Reason: May have different reasons but in my case occure when try to use arrays as property for returned structure. C# will see array of string as string.

Solve: I solved it by using basic types.

Note: if you know better way please comment it