Error on calling SOAP on .NET 8 { Element 'faultstring' with namespace name '' was not found. Line 6, position 115. }
I'm creating a console app calling a SOAP webserver using C# and Visual Studio connected services, which generates the contract classes for me.
But when I call a method from webservice, I'm not receiving the correct error message, no matter what I do. I always receive:

"Element 'faultstring' with namespace name '' was not found. Line 6, position 115."

Reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/55999753/5508407, seems to be a problem at the order of the fault creation message, but I don't know how to solve this.
I'm using .NET 8.

WSDL url:
https://sigafhomologa.mg.gov.br/webserver/soap_server.php?wsdl
Project source code: Github
Code:
using sigaf;

var login = new loginRequest("315500", "Wt2023"); //homol

var client = new Sigaf_projetoPortTypeClient();

try
{
    var loginrequest = new loginRequest(login.user, login.password);
    var token = await client.loginAsync(loginrequest);

    //Wrong Base64 text, should receive a XML FAULT from Webserver
    var receiveDataRequest = new recebeDadosRequest(token.@return, Convert.FromBase64String(
        "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"
        ));

    var response = await client.recebeDadosAsync(receiveDataRequest);

    Console.WriteLine(token.@return);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
}

Console.ReadLine();


Works as expected on SoapUI (receiving the Fault code and message):


Hello, can you upload the code to github? I can't see your code on OneDrive at the moment.

I've uploaded to github: https://github.com/DaybsonPaisante/soapdemo.git

I went through the following tests:1. ex.InnerException.Message change to ex.InnerException. Prompt me that the problem is in System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedFault.CreateFault11(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 maxBufferSize) and in System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageFault.CreateFault(Message message, Int32 maxBufferSize). But I searched through the library and didn't find either method.

2.I didn't find any way to do it in System.Exception either. I searched a lot more and I thought you could use System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector. This is document.
